# Neo4j Iterable<String> getPropertyKeys() loops infinitely? is this a bug?

Tags: java, neo4j, iterable, embedded-database

I am simply trying to copy the property keys from a relationship.  If I use this code.

```
        Iterable<String> tempkeys;
        tempkeys=  rel.getPropertyKeys();
        while (tempkeys.iterator().hasNext()){
            String key = tempkeys.iterator().next();
            System.out.println(key);
        }
```

it loops infinitely. If I recast the Iterable as an Arraylist then it works perfectly

```
        ArrayList<String> tempkeys;
        tempkeys= (ArrayList<String>) rel.getPropertyKeys();
        for (int i=0;i<=tempkeys.size();i++) {
            String key = tempkeys.iterator().next();
            System.out.println(key);
        }
```

If I debug the code it is evident that the iterable counter resets to 0 after each call of .next().  It increments to 1 during the call, but is back to 0 when the next call to .hasNext() is made.

The context is a follows.

```
    try (Transaction tx = this.graphDb.beginTx()) {
        Node Node1 = JavaCluster.AddUniqueNode("Element", "Name", "Node1");
        Node Node2 = JavaCluster.AddUniqueNode("Element", "Name", "Node2");
        RelationshipType tt = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("rt");
        Relationship rel = Node1.createRelationshipTo(Node2, tt);
        rel.setProperty("prop1", "propval1");
        rel.setProperty("prop2", "propval2");
        ArrayList<String> tempkeys;
        tempkeys= (ArrayList<String>) rel.getPropertyKeys();
        for (int i=0;i<=tempkeys.size();i++) {
            String key = tempkeys.iterator().next();
            System.out.println(key);
        }
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error - exception " + e.toString());
        //throw new TransactionFailException("Transaction failed",e);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You craete a new iterator in each iteration of the loop, which means `tempkeys.iterator().hasNext()` always returns `true` and `String key = tempkeys.iterator().next();` always returns the first element.

You should create an iterator once, outside the loop, and use the same iterator in each call to `next()` and `hasNext()`.

```
    Iterable<String> tempkeys;
    tempkeys = rel.getPropertyKeys();
    Iterator<String> iter = tempkeys.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next();
        System.out.println(key);
    }
```

BTW, your second loop (the for loop), while it doesn't produce an infinite loop, is still wrong, since it will return the first element of the list in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks,The odd thing is that an equivalent loop in the main code Iterable<Relationship> oldlinks = entity.getRelationships(Direction.INCOMING);
                                    while (oldlinks.iterator().hasNext()) {
                                    temprel = oldlinks.iterator().next();}    works perfectly.  Why do some iterators get recreated by the code and other don't?

Comment: The second loop was of course incorrectly edited and does actually produce the correct code.  In the actual code it reads newtemprel.setProperty(tempkeys.get(i), temprel.getProperty(tempkeys.get(i))); or equavvalently in the code above Steing key=tempkeys.get(i);